# Cannot remove dynamic UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

The UIButton is created under @implementation . I have to remove it after some functions but`[button removeFromSuperview]` doesn't work. How can I remove that?

```
#import "TabBar.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
@interface TabBar ()

@end

@implementation TabBar
UILabel *title;
NSString *par;
UIButton *button;

NSMutableArray *backlist;

- (NSString *)documentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
-(void)tbl_info{
    NSString *path = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"icd10.plist"];

    self.dataList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];    
    for (NSInteger i=[self.dataList count]-1; i>=0;i--) {
        NSDictionary *d = [self.dataList objectAtIndex:i];
        par=[d objectForKey:@"PARENTID"];
        if(![par isEqualToString:self.val])
            [self.dataList removeObjectAtIndex:i];


    }
}

- (IBAction)ara:(id)sender{
    [self tbl_info];
    [self.tViewTab reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataList count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *name= [[self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"NAME"];
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320/2, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [name sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    if(labelSize.height>=63)
        labelSize.height=63;
    return labelSize.height+1;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellid";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CustomCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                              loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil]
                             lastObject];
    }

    NSDictionary *d = [self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [d objectForKey:@"NAME"];
    cell.cityLabel.text = [d objectForKey:@"CODE"];
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320/2, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize nameSize = [cell.nameLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    if(nameSize.height>=63)
        nameSize.height=63;
    cell.nameLabel.frame =CGRectMake(80, 0, 234, nameSize.height);
    cell.cityLabel.text = [d objectForKey:@"CODE"];
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *d = [self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableDictionary *backprop = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [backprop setObject:self.val forKey:@"id"];
    [backprop setObject:title.text forKey:@"name"];

    [backlist addObject:backprop];

    //back button
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:title.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(02.0, 02.0, 71, 32);
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    //parent and title label
    [title setText:[d objectForKey:@"NAME"]];
    self.val=[d objectForKey:@"ID"];    

    [self tbl_info];
    [self.tViewTab reloadData];

}
-(void)touchEvent:(id)sender{
    [title setText:[[backlist objectAtIndex:backlist.count-1] objectForKey:@"name" ]];
    self.val= [[backlist objectAtIndex:backlist.count-1] objectForKey:@"id"];
    [backlist removeObjectAtIndex:backlist.count-1];
    if(backlist.count>0)
        [button setTitle:[[backlist objectAtIndex:backlist.count-1] objectForKey:@"name" ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [button removeFromSuperview];

    [self tbl_info];
    [self.tViewTab reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        backlist =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.val=@"0";
    [self tbl_info];
    [self.tViewTab reloadData];

    title =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(79.0, 07.0, 162, 21)];
    title.text = @"ICD10 Kod Grupları"; //etc...
    [self.view addSubview:title];
    [title release];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: post the code where you add the button please

Comment: You can set the hidden property on the button also to hide it from view.

Comment: Show some more code. Show especially that `button` actually refers to the UIButton that was created and added dynamically.

Comment: @JohnWoods if he manages to hide it then he can easily remove it as well.

Comment: @HermannKlecker agreed.

Comment: @John ok I'll try that, but want to know why this not working :/

Comment: Most likely you are calling removeFromSuper view on the wrong button reference. - Really you need to post code for us to evaluate.

Comment: Ok! where are you calling removeFromSuperView, show that code?

Comment: Your button is an autoreleased object. It's likely that you have lost your reference to it when you call removeFromSuperView

Comment: But how can it lost it?

Comment: I dont know. Have to look.I'm at the beginner level.

Comment: Have you put a log in you else clause where you try to remove the button, to see if you're getting to that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution but a workaround:

Use

```
[sender removeFromSuperview];
```

or respectively, because sender is of type `id` and not `UIView*`:

```
[(UIButton*)sender removeFromSuperview];
```

But you could change sender to UIView* savely. 
-(void)touchEvent:(UIView *)sender{

Some even put `UIButton*` in there. I personally don't like that but it is quite save if you know for sure that the message is sent by `UIButtons` only.

Another workaround would be to set the .`tag` property of the button and then fetch the real buttom from `self.view` by its tag.

Comment: I did this [(UIButton*)sender removeFromSuperview];. But didn't work. I'm trying the last one.

Comment: Franky I am not 100% positive about the syntax of the type cast here. What would work is changing `sender` to `UIView*`or `UIButton*` or try `UIButton myButton = (UIButton*)sender; [myButton removeFromSuperview];'. However, please follow Samkit Jain's advice too, because you are creating (and sub-view'ing) a new instance of `UIButton` every time when a row is selected.

Comment: I'm going to try release the existing button before creating a new one. Maybe it can work.

Comment: It didn't work. I tried the tag too and didn't work again. I try to create non ARC Button.

Comment: Tag thing worked. Everytime the buttons are creating on the top of the others. I set tag value for buttons as 100.And I put this code before creating a new one. if(button!=nil) [[self.view viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Do you really need them being created on top of each other? From the distance that sounds strange to me. However, first thanks for the accexp. Second - I think that using the .tag thing is nor really a solution. When I wrote that I did not realize that you were creating an number of buttons on top of each other. With aid of the tag you will fetch only one of them. Probably the first or the last added, I don't know. Well, in a loop you could fetch all of them and reomve them all in one got. That could work. On the contrary 'sender' will give you the very one button that was touched.

Comment: Yes they are the back buttons. They have to be top there and on top eachother. But it's ok. When I create another one I will remove the old one. So they are like first-last button. Because there isn't any other. I think I can use the tag like class in css?

Comment: The `tag` property does not have any specific use. You may use it for what ever you think is convenient. You could use it like classes in css but `tag` is cliearly of numeric type and there is one `tag` per UIView only.

Answer (score 1):

In place of this :

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:title.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(02.0, 02.0, 71, 32);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Try this :

```
 if (button != nil) {
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:title.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(02.0, 02.0, 71, 32);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
 }
```

Or try this :

```
if (button != nil) {
    [button removeFromSuperView];
    [button release]; // dont write this in case of ARC
    button = nil;
 }
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:title.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(02.0, 02.0, 71, 32);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: You are right. It could well be that he's crecated hundrets of buttons but only one of them is removed each time when the button is pressed. Even if there are only row buttons then he would not notice that one has been removed. And if it is removed then it's ony the newest one that will be removed unless he follows my advice on removing `sender` instead of `button`.

Comment: Dear Herman, He doesn't want to remove button when it is clicked. I think you can understand.

Comment: I just want to remove the button when there is no parents left to go back. If there is still parents to go back just the title changes as the name of the parent. Like a hierarchy. And these not worked.:/

Comment: I solved the problem. These buttons are back buttons. There is a category list. So it makes them the main parents. And in that view there has to be no back button, because they dont have parents. They are the main parents. But when I select one category the children of the selected category will be shown and there has to be a back button to the previous view to make it easy for the user.But when the back buttons were created and go back to main page, the last button wasn't removed. The reason was that they all created on top of eachother.I wrote the solution under Hermanns answer.Thank youtoo.